# `base64()` is not public in `android.util.base64()`

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the [base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class.

But I get this error

```
`base64()` is not public in `android.util.base64()`. 
 Cannot be accessed from outside package.
```

Here is how I use it:

```
package com.example.myname.myapp;
//...
import import android.util.Base64;
//...
Base64 base64 = new Base64(); //Here I get the error
//...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[android.util.Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) has no public constructors so it can't be instantiated directly. There is no need to create an instance anyway as the public API methods  are all static.

Comment: Thanks, that's eventually what I realized. It's a utility class, thus the name util!